# Nextjs link 3 copy of css . Anyone see this issue?

Tags: next.js13

[image]I have a page in app/dashboard directory in nextjs 13. But when i looked at head element of the page , it shows it has 3 links for same css. scss compiled into page.css but 3 links.

```
    "use client";
    import "./dashboard.scss";

    const Dashboard = () => {
          return (
            <div className="home">
            <div className="homeContainer">
       </div>
    </div>
     );
    };

     export default Dashboard;
```